# Проблема с picassoLoader android

Tags: android, picasso, android-imageview

При загрузке с помощью `BitmapFactory.DecodeStream()` изменял уже `bitmap` под максимальную ширину и уже ее вставлял в `imageView`. Появилась надобность делать это из главного потока.

Вопрос такой можно ли изменить ширину и высоту загружаемой картинки в Picasso?

Comment: https://futurestud.io/blog/picasso-image-resizing-scaling-and-fit

Answer (score 1):

Да можно, вот пример из оф источника.

```
Picasso
.with(context)
.load(UsageExampleListViewAdapter.eatFoodyImages[0])
.resize(600, 200) // resizes the image to these dimensions (in pixel). does not respect aspect ratio
.into(imageViewResize);
```

[Picasso](https://futurestud.io/blog/picasso-image-resizing-scaling-and-fit)

Comment: а можно ли сделать resize по одному параметру, просто на деле не известно какая высота .jpg файла, вернее они всегда разные